# How to integrate mobileiron sdk in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, enterprise, mobileiron

I am working on a enterprise level app in iOS. I need to secure it using [Appconnect's mobileiron](http://info.mobileiron.com/rs/mobileiron/images/appconnect_faq.pdf). I did not find the sdk for iOS and its related integration info in [mobileiron](https://www.mobileiron.com/en) website. Do I need to get a [paid subscription](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/products/pricing) to get its sdk? Can I get a step by step info on this?

I don't know if I should post this question here as I did not find appconnect or mobileiron tag in this website forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need access to the MobileIron developer portal by reviewing and accepting the AppConnect SDK agreement. Visit https://info.mobileiron.com/FY13-AppConnect-SDK-Program_Registration-Page.html to enroll yourself.
But keep in mind that for a complete development cycle you will need access to a MobileIron infrastructure to integrate and test your product.